# How to upload two different files to database from two diffrent inputs

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload two images from two different inputs to database but only the last one does get uploaded and it's name get duplicated into the two different columns in database. I tried some other solutions but it didn't work and if there a solution using javascript I accept that just help me please

here is the code.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    
    if(!isset($_SESSION['id'],$_SESSION['user_role_id']))
    {
        header('location:index.php?lmsg=true');
        exit;
    }       
    require_once('layouts/left_sidebar1.php'); 
    require_once('inc/config.php');



    if(isset($_POST['add'])){
        $code = trim($_POST['code']);
        $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $code);

        $nconformetxt = trim($_POST['nconformetxt']);
        $nconformetxt = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $nconformetxt);

        if(isset($_FILES['nconformeimg']) && $_FILES['nconformeimg']['name'] != ""){
            $nconformeimg = $_FILES['nconformeimg']['name'];
            $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $uploadDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . "images/";
            $uploadDirectory .= $nconformeimg;
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["nconformeimg"]["name"]);
            $newfilename1 = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["nconformeimg"]["tmp_name"], "images/{$newfilename1}");
        }
        
        $defaut = trim($_POST['defaut']);
        $defaut = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $defaut);

        $conformetxt = trim($_POST['conformetxt']);
        $conformetxt = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $conformetxt);

        if(isset($_FILES['conformeimg']) && $_FILES['conformeimg']['name'] != ""){
            $conformeimg = $_FILES['conformeimg']['name'];
            $directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $uploadDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . "images/";
            $uploadDirectory .= $conformeimg;
            $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["conformeimg"]["name"]);
            $newfilename = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($temp);
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["conformeimg"]["tmp_name"], "images/{$newfilename}");
        }
        
        $accepta = trim($_POST['accepta']);
        $accepta = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $accepta);  

        $pdreaction = trim($_POST['pdreaction']);
        $pdreaction = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $pdreaction);
        
        $id = '';

        $query = "INSERT INTO demo.defautheque   VALUES ('" . $id . "', '" . $code . "', '" . $nconformetxt . "', '" . $newfilename1 . "', '" . $defaut . "', '" . $conformetxt . "', '" . $newfilename . "', '" . $accepta . "', '" . $pdreaction . "')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        if(!$result){
            echo "Can't add new data " . mysqli_error($conn);
            exit;
        } else {
            $extra="defautheque.php";
            echo "<script>window.location.href='".$extra."'</script>";
        }
    }

?>

<div class="form-popup" id="myForm" style="left: 450px;width: 500px;box-shadow:0 10px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19) !important;">
    <div class="card" style="width: 500px;box-shadow:0 10px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19) !important;">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="card-title">Nouveau Plan d'Action</h5>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 1000px;" class="card-body">
                <form method="post" action="defautheque.php" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-2">
                            <label class="form-label" >Code</label>
                            <input type="text" name="code" class="form-control" placeholder="Code..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-4">
                            <label class="form-label" >Défaut</label>
                            
                            <input type="text" name="defaut" class="form-control" placeholder="Projet..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" >Non Conforme</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nconformetxt" class="form-control" placeholder="Non Conforme..">
                            <input type="file" name="nconformeimg" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                            <label class="form-label" >Conforme</label>
                            <input type="text" name="conformetxt" class="form-control" placeholder="Conforme..">
                            <input type="file" name="conformeimg" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label" >Acceptation</label>
                            <input type="text" name="accepta" class="form-control" placeholder="Acceptatin..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3 col-md-3">
                            <label class="form-label" >Plan de réaction</label>
                            
                            <input type="text" name="pdreaction" class="form-control" placeholder="Plan de réaction..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="margin-left: 330px;">
                        <input type="submit" name="add" value="Ajouter" class="btn btn-primary">
                        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first insert statement tries to use variables before they are defined. Probably this is failing. Are you not logging all errors and warnings? Make sure you're doing that, and make sure mysqli is set to throw errors when SQL problems occur.

Comment: P.s. this is all horrendously vulnerable both to SQL injection attacks and to unexpected SQL syntax errors. You should urgently learn how to use prepared statements and parameters, in order to run your queries securely and reliably.

Comment: I think there is no errors the problem it moves only the last file so I need a solution to move every file to the folder

Comment: Yes but the errors, if you tracked them, would help to explain why it's happening. Do you understand that your logic is backwards? You're trying to insert data like the filename into the database, before you have actually defined the filename! Clearly that will never work.

Comment: oh sorry that line was a mistake I was trying to insert every variable separately by inserting the first variable and then updating table after every variable.my bad. anyway is there a solution and I used ini_set('display_errors', '1'); to try see if there any errors but there are no errors. If you have another way to move files separately. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. and it is a very small one..when it generates the new name both files gets the same name. I thought because it generates name depending on microseconds there will be no problem but I was wrong because both names get generated at the same time, so what I did :

I only added '1' before the dot and it worked.

$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["nconformeimg"]["name"]);
$newncomforme= round(microtime(true)) . '1.' . end($temp);